# Logic behind choosing $\phi(x)$ in following Question

Tags: calculus

If $ f'(x), g'(x) $ exist for all $x \in [a,b]$ and if $g'(x)$ does not vanish anywhere on (a,b) then prove that $\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(c)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$.

This is standard text book problem. If we take $\phi(x) = f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(x)-g(b)f(x)$ and apply Rolle's theorem i will get required one

But i did not understand how to pick such $\phi(x)$. I thought but i could not initially get such $\phi$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Rewrite the conclusion as $(f(c) - f(a)) g'(c) - (g(b) - g(c)) f'(c) =0$ and integrate the expression with respect to $c$. Change the $c$ to $x$ and you get $\phi(x) $.

Comment: There is a typo in question. You should have $\dfrac{f(c) - f(a)} {g(b) - g(c)} $. You have used $g(b) - g(a) $ in denominator.

Comment: yes you are right. thnx for clarification. can you tell me how to remember $T_{n+1}$ term in taylor's series. Often i forget in my term exams. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512319/how-to-remember-t-n1-in-taylors-theorem