# How to remember $T_{n+1}$ in taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus

I always forget $T_{n+1}$  remainder term in my term exams. I know that in taylor's theorem, (n+1)th term $T_{n+1} = \frac{(b-c)^{(n-p)}(b-a)^p}{p (n-1)!} f^{(n)}(c)$ for given function $f(x)$ and interval $[a,b]$ and $a<c<b$

In the end i only remember lagrangian remainder term. Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually remember the proof via integration. And then it is easy to apply mean value theorem on the reminder in integral form.

Comment: hmm... actually i have not gone thru the proof. let me go thru